# cannot see pvob on clearcase GUI?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I cannot see pvob on clearcase GUI but when I list the vobs in command line (cleartool lsvob -s), I can see it.

In order to make it visible on the clearcase GUI, what are the necessary steps should I take?

Also it looks like a private Pvob, how can I make it public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pvobs are visible in the ClearCase Project Explorer (type `clearprojexp`), not in the ClearCase Explorer ('`clearexplorer`').

The pvob could be used as a vob, but it normally is used only as a referential for UCM metadata (projects, streams, activities...), and not for data (files/directories).
It is an Admin vob for other (data) vobs, which explains why you don't see it in the ClearCase explorer.

For your second question, you need to use the [`cleartool mkvob` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkvob.htm):

#### UNIX, Linux, and Windows: Private-to-public VOB conversion

> To convert a private VOB to a public VOB, use a command like this:

```
cleartool mktag -vob -tag \vob3.p -replace -public \\saturn\users\vbstore\private3.vbs
```

> This replaces the VOB's private VOB tag with a public one.
>   `mktag` prompts you to enter the VOB tag password.

Comment: I am still not been able to see the pvob on clearcase project explorer. Here what I have done so far:

Comment: I am still not been able to see the pvob on clearcase project explorer. Here what I have done so far:linux1!tello.2: cleartool mkvob -tag /vobs/spider1_pvob -c "test source" /wells/vobstore/tcp/spider1_pvob.vbs Created versioned object base. cleartool mktag -vob -tag /vobs/spider1_pvob -replace -public /ots/welltt1/vobstore/tcp/spider1_pvob.vbs

Comment: @user2370590 first, you can make a vob public from the `mkvob` step, you don't need two `mkvob` commands for that. Second, a pvob would be a `mkvob -ucm`: it is the `-ucm` which makes it a pvob.