# What is the Difference between VOB and PVOB?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

What I understand is that,
 ***PVOB*** is a special type of VOB that is used when UCM is
implemented as the software configuration management process.

But my doubt is how is it different from VOB? I am new to CC but, as far as I know, even PVOB contains the same information as VOB.

Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PVob is like a vob in that it *can* version files and folders.

But by convention, you don't use a pvob to "add to source control".

You use a PVob as a "admin vob" for a classic Vob in order to declare component(s) in it, and to manage all the matadata associated to UCM:

- Projects
- Streams
- Activity
- Merge Hyperlinks for deliver and rebase

In that case, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943275/6309), PVob are visible in the ClearCase *project* Explorer, not the ClearCase Explorer.

As any "AdminVob", a pvob manages datatypes for the associated vobs: see "[VOB datatypes and administrative VOB hierarchies](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/type-admin.htm)".
Simply, a pvob will manage *UCM* types as well, making projects, streams and activities visibles for all the associated UCM vobs (which contain the actual data).

You can actually group pvob in a hierarchy, as explained in "[Multiple PVOBs and a common administrative VOB](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_ucm_plan_pvobmult_admin.htm)".

> If projects in one PVOB need to modify components in other PVOBs, your Rational® ClearCase® administrator needs to identify one PVOB to serve as a common administrative VOB for the PVOBs and the component VOBs.
>
> In Figure 1, PVOB1 and PVOB2 use PVOB3 as their administrative VOB.

[image: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/images/multi_pvobs_linked.gif]

Comment: Can you explain me what is the work of the admin VOB? or can you direct me to a link which explains the same..!!

Comment: @HarishTalanki I have edited the answer to address your question.