# Clearcase - Not able to search files and texts in Component VOB

Tags: clearcase

I have clearcase Rational Clearcase Remote Client Version: 7.1.0.0 installed on my machine. I have created my view by creating workspace and using CVOB for repository. I am not able search from search menu like file, text within the file as its always returning 0 matches. Do i need to configure or install additionally to enable search?  My organization is using clear case a strategic solution for documentation repository and as search is not working at whole rollout will go for toss. Appreciate if anyone has solution on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not search in a pvob: it should be for UCM metadata only (poject, activities, ...)

You should use a Vob (an UCM one probably, where an UCM component root has been defined)

In that vob, you will find elements (directories and files) to search for.

See more at "[What is the Difference between VOB and PVOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281992/6309)".

Comment: i have VOB structure as well as its giving me the same result.

Comment: @user3445233 can you edit your question and copy the config spec of your view. (or put a screenshot of said config spec)