# How to find all the component root folder in a vob?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769815/how-to-find-rootfolder-for-each-component-using-cleartool) long back and the answer was given. Now i would like to get all the component root folder in a vob.

The answer in that question was if i give the component name ,it will give the root folder. But now my vob contains plenty of components and it was tough for me to enter each component.

What is the cleartool command for finding all the component root folder in a vob?

Answer (score 1):

That would be [`cleartool lscomp`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscomp.htm?lang=en), for listing all the component names.
For each component name, you can the call the routine described in "[how to find `root[folder]` for each component using `cleartool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769988/6309)"

```
cleartool lscomp -s -invob \aVobTag
```

(with `-s`, you only get the name, not the extended name)

As in:

```
cleartool lscomp -invob /vobs_projects
cleartool lscomp -invob \vobs_projects # on Windows
2007-09-17T12:06:59  vobs_parser  bill
root directory: "/vobs_parser"
2007-03-29T17:23:16  vobs_applets  pklenk
root directory: "/vobs_applets"
```

Note that `/vobs_projects` is a pvob (project pvob).

```
–inv/ob vob-selector
```

> Displays information for all components in the specified **project VOB**.

See "[What is the Difference between VOB and PVOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281992/6309)".

Comment: This is the command i have executed M:\MyView\MyVob>cleartool lscomp -invob /MyVob . I am getting the following error . cleartool: Error: Not a UCM PVOB: "/MyVob".

Comment: @Samselvaprabu a vob or pvob *tag* in Windows should start with `\`: `\MyVob`. And you can list components in a pvob only (UCM metadata), not a vob (data: files and directories).

Comment: @Samselvaprabu See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21281992/6309 and my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27459889/6309

Comment: If i try with Pvob name , it also throws error.                 M:\ViewNameMyVob\IPC>cleartool lscomp -invob /a_Pvob
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "/a_Pvob".

Comment: @Samselvaprabu again, a tag in Windows starts with `\\`. `\aPvob`