# Archive UCM Clearcase VOBS

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am in a Windows environment and we need to close down our UCM ClearCase instance. As part of that process, we need to back up and then remove all UCM Project & Component VOBS.

If it had been base ClearCase, I would have:

- Undo any checkouts
- removed views
- lock the vob
- unmount

Then zip up the vob in the vob store before using an rmvob to remove it.

Do I or should I do anything different for UCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCM means admin vobs, specifically UCM PVobs. You need to take care of those once you have taken care of the regular data vobs.

PVob will include all UCM metadata (project, stream and activities, baselines, ...): see "[What is the Difference between VOB and PVOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281992/6309)"

So once the regular vobs have been archived *first*, you need to archive the pvob and/or admin vobs as well.

Check also a [few pre-requisite of the backup tool you will use to make the Vob archive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_backup.htm).